# Magento2 : customer_account_create event is not triggering

Tags: event-observer, customer-account, magento-2.1.7

I have created a custom module, and added event in `etc/events.xml` as below :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_account_create">
        <observer name="customizecustomer_accountcreate" instance="Module\Custom\Model\Accountcreate" shared="false" />
    </event>
</config>
```

And created a file `Model/Accountcreate.php` as below :

```
namespace Module\Custom\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class Accountcreate implements ObserverInterface
{

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/customer.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info('Accountcreate'); // to check if event is working or not

    }
}
```

Also executed below commands :

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

But when I'm trying to register as customer the event is not calling.

I want to add some server side validation on customer account create.

Am I doing anything wrong? Is there any another event which trigger before account create?

Comment: Check my answer it will help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no event `customer_account_create`

You can use `customer_register_success` for customer register success.

You can see all the event list [here](https://www.simicart.com/blog/magento-2-events-list/).

Or

You can use this event for validation.

> controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_createpost

Magento is using this event for validating captcha.

Comment: I want to add some custom validation before customer account create with the data what customer enter, and don't allow to register if validation failed.

Comment: @VinayaMaheshwari You can create your one custom event.

Comment: @VinayaMaheshwari check my updated answer.

Comment: I have added `controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_createpost` and also validation on form fields but how to throw exception if validation failed?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of overriding, you can create a custom plugin (the new concept introduced in Magento 2).

Ref. Links:

- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html
- https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-use-plugins/
- https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-plugin-interceptor.html

Benefits of using plugins instead of overriding functions:

- “Listen” to any method call made on an object manager controlled
  object and take programmatic action
- Change the return value of any method call made on an object manager
  controlled object
- Change the arguments of any method call made to an object manager
  controlled object