# Create event and observer for customer sign up (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, event-observer, customer-account

How can I create my own `event` and `observer` for customer sign up, 
From this link,

> [Magento2 : customer_account_create event is not triggering](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/226902/magento2-customer-account-create-event-is-not-triggering)

I found that We can use `customer_register_success` for customer register success.

So I found that events.xml in `/module-persistent/etc/webapi_rest/events.xml`

```
<event name="customer_register_success">
    <observer name="persistent" instance="Magento\Persistent\Observer\RemovePersistentCookieOnRegisterObserver" />
</event>
```

So observer file is `RemovePersistentCookieOnRegisterObserver.php`
I want to make my custom `event` and `observer` for customer sign up, how to achieve that and where should I write my custom events and observer.

This is my code

```
 namespace YX\Customer\Observer

 class RegisterSuccess implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{

protected  $customlogger;
protected  $tempblock;
protected  $customerHelper;


public function __construct(
    \Rage\Base\Helper\CustomLogger $loggerHelper
     \YX\Catalog\Block\OrderHelper $orderHelper,
    \YX\Customer\Helper\CustomerHelper $customerHelper

)
{
    $this->customlogger = $loggerHelper->getLogger('custom');
    $this->tempblock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('YX\Catalog\Block\OrderHelper');
    $this->customerHelper = $this->helper('YX\Customer\Helper\CustomerHelper');
}
public function execute(
    \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
) {

 \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
        ->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class)->debug("here in customer 
 login before func " .$this->customerHelper->isCustomer());

    if (!($this->customerHelper->isCustomer())){
        $customerID = $this->customerHelper->getCustomerId();
        $orderId = $this->customerHelper->getOrderId();
        $this->tempblock->guestToCustomer($orderId,$customerID);

    }
}
```

}

I have put  dubgger logs but still, on the user sign up it doesn't go inside execute() function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this,

> Create this file in the path app/code/vendor/module/etc/events.xml
>   For example ,

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="customer_register_success">
    <observer instance="vendor\modulename\Observer\Customer\RegisterSuccess" name="customer_register_succes"/>
</event>
```

then

> Place the respective observer file in the folder defined like app/code/vendor/module/Observer/Customer/RegisterSuccess.php

```
<?php                                                         
 namespace vendor\module\Observer\Customer;                        
 class RegisterSuccess implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface                                
 {

public function __construct(
    ......
    ......
    )
{
    ......
}
public function execute(
    \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
) {

    $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getData('customer');

}}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: @G Prathap it didnt work, the events will call automatically on customer registration ?

Comment: Yes it does working. I have checked and given answer

Comment: Dont you think we have to Dispatch events so that observer can catch it . https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/events-and-observers.html

Comment: It's for creating new events but in our case customer registration success event is an core one. So we don't require that. Check again if it is done correctly or update a question with you code, I'll figure it out

Comment: @G Prathap I have updated the question

Comment: @G Prathap i Dont understand why your observer php class has namespace namespace vendor\module\Observer\Customer; , shouldnt be it just be   namespace vendor\module\Observer as this file in observer folder

Comment: @summu Yes it can anything that mention in as instance in events.xml

Comment: It worked, I updated my module version in XML and ran setup: upgrade then it started to read code from my observer, so you need to update your version of module and then setup: upgrade

Comment: Observers doesn't require those, only when you have upgradeschema and upgradedata then you gotta updated module.xml to setup:upgrade to make  it working. Anyway glad it worked out for you. Guess you module were not installed that's why it started working after setup:upgrade.
Thanks

Comment: Module was installed I checked it in setup module table , but anyhow I was everything to make it work